# Office apps is unable to show Web Add-in's taskpane due to a Win32WebViewHost.exe issue

Tags: office-js, office-addins

With the intention to clear a web addin's cache, I deleted, by mistake, this whole folder `"C:\Users\[CUR_USER]\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy"`, and since then, Word is not able to show my addin using the taskpane. To add insult to injury, the same issue applies to all the other web addins (installed from Office Store) and this also was tested and confirmed for Excel & PowerPoint as well.

**Edit**: I can now confirm adding Outlook to the list of victims! so, no web addin, either local or from the store could be run in MS Office apps, not anymore!

I got the following error msg across all the addins:

```
ADD-IN ERROR
This add-in could not be started. 
Close this dialog to ignore the problem or click "Restart" to try again.
```

[image]

Checking the windows event's log, I see the following error:

```
Faulting application name: Win32WebViewHost.exe, version: 10.0.18362.959, time stamp: 0x297477f6
Faulting module name: edgemanager.dll, version: 11.0.18362.959, time stamp: 0xa3f2202d
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000003167b
Faulting process id: 0x290c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d662923a27c6d8
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\Win32WebViewHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\edgemanager.dll
Report Id: 272dc83b-a678-40c7-a9f2-09a22a1f9910
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_10.0.18362.449_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: DPI.PerMonitorAware
```

I then created a new Windows user profile, logged-in, and tested a few addins in Word and it was working as expected, I then copied this folder `[Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy]` from this newly-created user profile to my user profile and tested but without luck, it still not working!

Back to our new-user profile, I renamed the folder in question, relaunch Word and, as I expected, all addins stopped working, I revert the folder name back to its original name and tested again.. and, as I didn't expected, the issue still there although the folder is there as it was created!!!

I searched the whole google and bing to look for a solution without any quasi-solution or helpful suggestions/hints. I tried to re-install (reset) `Edge` and `Win32WebViewHost` in my user profile, I also thought about resetting my local user account but without any results so far!

So, if anyone there had encountered this issue before or know what is really happening there, please provide some help.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this should be considered a valid answer but I'll post it anyway!

I didn't do anything to my computer, it just finished installing the latest windows 10 update, `Version 2004, Build 19041.388` and after restarting & applying the update, everything was working like in the past.

Answer (score -1):

Oh how the heavens of webview can crash down upon a code soul

Try a value of 100 in the final code line through the shell

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).